# Bundle ID not transferred when transferring an app

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

We received a new transferred app from other company. Now we have to update its versions and release it on the App Store.

The problem is that we can see the app in iTunesConnect. But to upload a new version we need to have the Bundle ID and the existing Bundle ID is not shown.

How do we obtain it?

Comment: What bundle identifier is associated with the newly transferred application in [AppStoreConnect](http://appstoreconnect.apple.com)?

Comment: @GrahamMiln It is like com.abcxyzghi.theabcxyzghi

Comment: Can you use `com.abcxyzghi.theabcxyzghi` for your update? If not, [contact Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) and ask them what to do. They are best able to help you with your account and the transferred application.

Answer (score 1):

## Contact Apple Developer

[Contact Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) and ask them what to do. They are best able to help you with your account and the transferred application.

When I transferred applications the bundle identifier has remained unchanged.